# Testing state of a button

Tags: cypress

When I click a button via `cy.get('#numberOfFetusOne').click()` its class changes to selected. How can I validate this change of the class? If I try to get a class with `cy.get` I get an error: `Expected to find element: gpx-16 i1-regular gpu-selected, but never found it.`

```
<gpu-button-option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" id="numberOfFetusOne" value="Singleton" class="gpx-16 i1-regular" _nghost-udx-c95=""> 1 </gpu-button-option>
```

```
<gpu-button-option _ngcontent-udx-c111="" id="numberOfFetusOne" value="Singleton" class="gpx-16 i1-regular gpu-selected" _nghost-udx-c95=""> 1 </gpu-button-option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `should` assertion for this.

```js
cy.get('#numberOfFetusOne').should('have.class', 'gpu-selected')
```